# Best way to bulk insert XML data into SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I have to shred around 25 - 30 XMLs into my SQL Server 2005 database (the total size would be around 10 MB). And I need this logic to run automatically as soon as new xml files are copied to the server.

Ive read many posts on this site and also other sites, but can't still conclude on what must I use to shred data.

Pls let me know which option must I should go with

1. SqlBulk Copy
2. C# deserialization
3. SSIS

I have to create C# classes for my data models. So C# deserialization was my first choice.
But pls let me know which option will be right from a performance perspective.

Another thing I forgot to mention was the structure of the XML files will vary. It wouldnt be the same. I will have tables that will have all the columns that could possibly be populated. But the xmls will not have all the data at all times.

Sample of the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<estateList date="2012-08-06T12:17:05">
  <uniqueID>22XXln</uniqueID>
  <category name="Apartment" /> 
  <listingAgent>
     <name>DIW Office</name>  
     <telephone type="BH">96232 2345</telephone> 
     <telephone type="BH">9234 2399</telephone>
     <email>abcd@abc.com</email>    
  </listingAgent>
  <inspectionTimes /> 
  <description>AVAILABLE NOW. </description> 
  <price>0</price>  
  <address display="yes">      
    <street>Lachlsan Street</street>        
    <ImagesContainer>        
       <img id="m" modTime="2012-08-06-12:17:05" url="http://images/2409802.jpg" format="jpg" /> 
       <img id="a" modTime="2012-08-06-12:17:05" /> 
    </ImagesContainer>     
  </address>
</estateList>
```

Thanks.

Comment: We have our database on Sql server 2005. The logic I write will have to run every time new xml files are dropped to the location.

Comment: Could be once in 10 days or even more frequent.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have a table named estateList and each and every element is my column. I need the value of the date, name of the apartment, Listing agent's name (DIW office).

Comment: How do you handle the multiple `<telephone>` or `<img>` elements?

Comment: I have multiple telephone columns in the db. For the img, I have to insert the unique id and the values of the image urls into another sql table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you have your XML in a SQL variabe, you can pretty easily parse out most of the info using straight T-SQL with the XQuery support added in SQL Server 2005.

Try something like:

```
DECLARE @Input XML = '<estateList date="2012-08-06T12:17:05">
  <uniqueID>22XXln</uniqueID>
  <category name="Apartment" /> 
  <listingAgent>
     <name>DIW Office</name>  
     <telephone type="BH">96232 2345</telephone> 
     <telephone type="BH">9234 2399</telephone>
     <email>abcd@abc.com</email>    
  </listingAgent>
  <inspectionTimes /> 
  <description>AVAILABLE NOW. </description> 
  <price>0</price>  
  <address display="yes">      
    <street>Lachlsan Street</street>        
    <ImagesContainer>        
       <img id="m" modTime="2012-08-06-12:17:05" url="http://images/2409802.jpg" format="jpg" /> 
       <img id="a" modTime="2012-08-06-12:17:05" /> 
    </ImagesContainer>     
  </address>
</estateList>'

SELECT
    EstateListDate = EstL.value('@date', 'datetime'),
    UniqueID = EstL.value('(uniqueID)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    Category = EstL.value('(category/@name)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    ListingAgentName = EstL.value('(listingAgent/name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ListingAgentTel = EstL.value('(listingAgent/telephone)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ListingAgentEMail = EstL.value('(listingAgent/email)[1]', 'varchar(250)'),
    [Description] = EstL.value('(description)[1]', 'varchar(250)'),
    Price = EstL.value('(price)[1]', 'decimal(14,2)'),
    DisplayAddress = EstL.value('(address/@display)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
    AddressStreet = EstL.value('(address/street)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM @input.nodes('/estateList') AS Tbl(EstL)
```

and you should get:

[image]

This data could be easily inserted into a table. And this query could be run against any number of XML files on disk, using a fairly easy SSIS package (enumerate the XML, load each into a SQL variable, parse it, insert data into tables etc.)

**BUT:** the challenging part is going to be questions like:

- can there be more than one listing agent? And if yes : how to handle that?
- can there be more than one phone number and how to deal with that?
- what do to with the multiple images per address

and so forth ....

**Update:** this query here would extract the `UniqueID` and each complete `<img>` tag's information from that XML input and display it (or insert it into another table):

```
SELECT
    UniqueID = @input.value('(/estateList/uniqueID)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    ImageID = Images.value('(img/@id)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    ImageModTime = Images.value('(img/@modTime)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ImageFormat = Images.value('(img/@format)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    ImageURL = Images.value('(img/@url)[1]', 'varchar(250)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/estateList/address/ImagesContainer') AS Tbl(Images)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc. I'll check for a few more xmls and come back. But thanks for giving me a direction. So you saying that I write this query against an SSIS package.

Comment: @Deefa: write this query (or multiple queries) and then execute those in a SSIS package - that seems to be the most sensible approach, I think. That SSIS package can be scheduled to run e.g. once every week on Monday 4am or whatever you need.....